# How to retrieve respective values using bitwise in angular

Tags: angular, typescript, bitwise-operators

I'm trying to retrieve value, which I originally saved into database as sum of bits. I am working in Angular 9 (Typescript).

I am successfully saving sum of bits into db. On another screen I want to display values, I'm getting from database the number (sum).

Let's say in my .ts file I have array of strings

```
  bitwiseLabels: string[] =
    ['Kitchen', 'Bedroom', 'Living Room'];
```

From db I'm getting back the number of 3, which is the sum of 1 and 2, so I want to display on a screen 'Kitchen' and 'Bedroom', respectively.
So far I didn't come up with any working solution, I hope someone here can advice.

Answer (score 2):

You can extract the original values using bit masks:

```js
const getSelections = (items, selection) =>
    items.filter((_, i) => selection & (1 << i));

const bitwiseLabels = ['kitchen', 'bedroom', 'living room'];

   
    
console.log(getSelections(bitwiseLabels, 3));

console.log(getSelections(bitwiseLabels, 4));

console.log(getSelections(bitwiseLabels, 5));

console.log(getSelections(bitwiseLabels, 6));

console.log(getSelections(bitwiseLabels, 7));
```

If you want to extract the separate numeric values, you can do this:

```js
const getSelections = (items, selection) =>
    items.map((_, i) => 1 << i).filter((i) => selection & i);

const bitwiseLabels = ['kitchen', 'bedroom', 'living room'];

   
    
console.log(getSelections(bitwiseLabels, 3));

console.log(getSelections(bitwiseLabels, 4));

console.log(getSelections(bitwiseLabels, 5));

console.log(getSelections(bitwiseLabels, 6));

console.log(getSelections(bitwiseLabels, 7));
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It's such an elegant solution :)